# Trying to find a book about aliens with clouds instead hair

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find a book which I used to read at university some years ago. I remember just some very scarce details. It was English or American SF about aliens who invaded and occupied the Earth. Human race was used by them as slaves. In the beginning of the book the story focuses on an alien girl who thought about human appearance and position in their some kind of society. Unlike humans aliens had clouds instead of hair. It would be very cool if you are able to help me.

Comment: It might be John Rowe Townsend's 'The Creatures', but it has been many years since I read it. It involves aliens (the unemotional 'Persons') who have occupied Earth and who look down on humans as an inferior species - 'Creatures'. In he course of the book two Persons - a boy and a girl - begin to wonder about human emotions and this makes them outcasts among their own people. I think the Persons had 'clouds instead of hair' but I can't remember for sure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It is exactly the same book which I used to read! Using your data I've found the description in the Internet and already checked our local library. Here it is: Townsend, J. R. King Creature, Come. - Leeds : E.J.Arnold & Son Ltd, 1988. - 187 p.  I am on my way to library)) Thank you again, you've made me completely happy :*

Comment: @LeeEckhardt care to turn that into a full-fledged answer, since we know now it's the right one? :)